# Do we really have to keep these properties AzureWebJobStorage and AzureWebJobDashboardn in .net webjob config file?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops, azure-webjobs, azureportal

**Issue:** If I am not keeping these two properties in appSettings.json **AzureWebJobStorage** and **AzureWebJobDashboar** then my web job throwing **ArgumentNullException (Parameter: connectionString) cannot be null.**

For temporary to fix this issue, we added these two keys in our appSettings.json with the same value that we have in our custom property.

As above, We have a separate property that holds the same storage connection string which we use/refer throughout the application.

We even debug and checked the value and is taking from our own custom property. Then we got a question like why we need this in our configuration file?

Is there is any way application should work without these **AzureWebJobStorage and AzureWebJobDashboard** properties?

Here I am looking,

1. I am not going to add these two properties in any of the config files.
2. I am not going to add these two properties the Azure portal web job configuration.

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: the `AzureWebJobDashboard` is optional but the `AzureWebJobStorage` is mandatory i think. why dont you want to add them ?

Comment: @Thomas - Thanks for answering and here I don't want to add them. But without adding those connectionStrings in an application is throwing an error.

Comment: i guess if you wanna use webjob you'll have to add it. You could add a key vault reference if you want to keep it secure. but you should explain why you dont want to add these settings

Comment: @Thomas - As mentioned in the post, I already configured my custom key which holds the storage connection string. My application uses this to store the files. That's the reason I don't want to include these extra sections in my configuration in my application and as well in Azure Portal. But I got to know from the official website which they mentioned AzureWebJobStorage key shuold keep in the connection string.